# Extract Data from one excel file to another excel file using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

Good Morning Everyone,

May i know how to extract all data from a excel file and copy the data all over to another excel file?

Example from Excel A, we have data

**EmployeeID    Name  Department**

1111           John      MIS

I want to copy the data over to Excel B... may i know how to do that using VB.net?

Please assist me!

Comment: `cmd.exe | copy excelA.xlsx excelB.xlsx`

Comment: Do you have an actual requirement to use vb.net for this?